# How do I change the values in one column based on a different column?

Tags: python, pandas

How do you change the values on `cola` based on `colb`?  For example, say I want to change the name where ID = 1,4,7?

```
ID Name
1  Name1
2  Name2
3  Name3
4  Name4
5  Name5
6  Name6
7  Name7
8  Name8
```

Preferably I want to use a dictionary, like so:

```
change = {
    1: 'foo',
    4: 'bar',
    7: 'baz'
}
```

And if I appy the change dictionary with a map like so:

```
df['Name'] = df['ID'].map(change)
```

However, it just changes the ID for 1,4, and 7.

```
ID Name
    1  foo
    2  
    3  
    4  bar
    5  
    6  
    7  baz
    8
```

Is there to only change the rows that are in my dictionary and ignore the rest? To get the result:

```
ID Name
1  foo
2  Name2
3  Name3
4  bar
5  Name5
6  Name6
7  baz
8  Name8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['Name'] = df['ID'].map(change).fillna(df['Name'])
print (df)
   ID   Name
0   1    foo
1   2  Name2
2   3  Name3
3   4    bar
4   5  Name5
5   6  Name6
6   7    baz
7   8  Name8
```

Or:

```
df['Name'] = df['ID'].map(change).combine_first(df['Name'])
print (df)
   ID   Name
0   1    foo
1   2  Name2
2   3  Name3
3   4    bar
4   5  Name5
5   6  Name6
6   7    baz
7   8  Name8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one with a masking method -

```
df.loc[df.ID.isin(change.keys()),'Name'] = change.values()
```

Sample run -

```
In [396]: df
Out[396]: 
   ID   Name
0   1  Name1
1   2  Name2
2   3  Name3
3   4  Name4
4   5  Name5
5   6  Name6
6   7  Name7
7   8  Name8

In [397]: df.loc[df.ID.isin(change.keys()),'Name'] = change.values()

In [398]: df
Out[398]: 
   ID   Name
0   1    foo
1   2  Name2
2   3  Name3
3   4    bar
4   5  Name5
5   6  Name6
6   7    baz
7   8  Name8
```